# Running QQ : Can't find Python 3.3.1 in apt-get or synaptic

Tags: installation, 12.10, apt, synaptic, python3

I'm running QQ : Can't find the repos/packages for Python 3.3.1 with apt-get or synaptic. How do I find them and install Python 3.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04, which includes Python 3.3.1, or [request a backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Requesting_New_Backports) of python3.3 to 12.10. Upgrading to 13.04 might be a good idea since you're on a non-LTS release already.

Comment: Seems like 13.04 isn't quite ready yet, at least judging from what I've seen from the questions here - especially with dual boot systems, which I have. I know 12.10 is not LTS but it has been very solid for me. Don't really want to move just yet. Backport? There must be an easier way!

Comment: 13.04 is now released, so it's as ready as it's ever going to get. There will be bug fixes, and other things over the next few months of course. I'm not sure what problems you're referring to, but it works fine for me on my dual booting laptop with Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/~python-dev/+archive/ppa

This ppa has version 3.3 which I have tested personally.

Comment: It did get me to 3.3, but no 3.3.1 there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't been able to find a way to install it either using apt-get or synaptic.  I did find it in .tar.bz2 file format.  You can download it [here](http://www.python.org/download/).

To find out how to install a .tar.bz2 files under Ubuntu, you might want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)